# Remotereader plugin not working with imageresizer

Tags: imageresizer

I m having problems with the remotereader plugin of Image resizer.

Everything is working fine on local server and Local IIS but when i placed site on Remote server it stops working with error message image url contain error.

exm: http://refp.client-staging.com/remote.jpg.ashx?width=526&urlb64=aHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3JlZnBzdGFnaW5nL3Byb3BlcnR5L25vLWltYWdlLnBuZw&hmac=OsF1TwAYgvA can't be load because its contain error.
In console it show 500 internal error.

The same plugin is working fine on local server.

I tried to match /resizer.debug.ashx from both local and remote server both are same. There is no difference between them.

I have also tried diagnosis as per imageresizer support but can't get any thing out of that.

Here is the resizer.debug.ashx output.

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      1/1/2014 10:14:38 AM

1 Issues detected:

(Warning):  Precompilation is enabled. Image providers may not work as expected.



You are using plugins from the Performance Edition: DiskCache (Performance Edition), RemoteReaderPlugin (Performance Edition)

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader.RemoteReaderPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<remotereader signingKey="[redacted]" allowAllSignedRequests="true"     allowRedirects="50000000000000">
<allow domain="imageresizing.net" />
<allow domain="*.imageresizing.net" onlyWhenSigned="true" />
</remotereader>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
<diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true"     subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760"     />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="RemoteReader" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR     4.0.30319.1008
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1008      Info: 4.0.30319.1008
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Data.SqlXml                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015  Info: 4.0.30319.1015
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.296  Info: 10.0.30319.296
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.20105.0    
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1         Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1015      Info: 4.0.30319.1015
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
REFP.csproj_deploy                       Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Cassette.Views                           Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
REFP.Core                                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Stripe.net                               Assembly: 1.2.0.0        
FluentValidation.Mvc                     Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0        
EntityFramework                          Assembly: 4.1.0.0         File: 4.1.10331.0     Info: 4.1.10331.0
System.Data.Entity                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1016  Info: 4.0.30319.1016
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Data.OracleClient                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1         Info: 4.0.30319.1
FluentValidation                         Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0        
Cassette                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.17974     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-REFP.Core  Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Elmah                                    Assembly: 1.2.13605.0     File: 1.2.13605.2128 
Cassette.Aspnet                          Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
AjaxMin                                  Assembly: 4.60.4609.17023
AWSSDK                                   Assembly: 1.3.19.0        File: 1.3.19.0       
BCrypt.Net                               Assembly: 0.1.4056.18965  File: 0.1.0.0        
CKFinder                                 Assembly: 2.2.0.1326     
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549       Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549       Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549       Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b
ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader        Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549       Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader            Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549       Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b
librets-dotnet                           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
LinqKit                                  Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.3.14814    
nunit.framework                          Assembly: 2.6.3.13283     Info: 2.6.3.13283
REFP                                     Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
RestSharp                                Assembly: 102.7.0.0       File: 102.7.0.0      
RouteDebug                               Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
seleniumtestcases                        Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Utilities                                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
WebDriver                                Assembly: 2.37.0.0        File: 2.37.0.0       
WebDriver.Support                        Assembly: 2.37.0.0        File: 2.37.0.0       
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Design                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237       Info: 4.0.30319.237
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
App_Web_hc0ar5ee                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_issnssr2                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Dynamic                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
App_Web_xii3ec4x                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_wzezwmsm                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_hhqs4kam                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_3uzvykdn                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_lip2j2wq                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_hjrxm4as                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.1           Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
pcln2wso                                 Assembly: 1.3.19.0       

The following plugin assemblies are loaded but do not seem to be in use. You should     remove them (and especially their dependencies (unless used elsewhere)) from the /bin     folder to improve application load times:

ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader            Assembly: 3.4.2.549       File: 3.4.2.549           Info: 3-4-2  Commit: dd7c30b

Reference list of plugin dependencies - so you know what additional dlls to remove when     removing a plugin. (may not be up-to-date, see plugin docs):

The FreeImage plugin has the following dependencies: FreeImage.dll and FreeImageNET.dll
The Logging plugin depends on: NLog.dll
The AdvancedFilters, RedEye, and WhitespaceTrimmer plugins depend on: AForge.dll,     AForge.Math.dll, and AForge.Imaging.dll
The PsdReader and PsdComposer plugins depend on: PsdFile.dll
The S3Reader plugin depends on: LitS3.dll
The BatchZipper plugin depends on: Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll
The PdfRenderer plugin depends on gsdll32.dll or gdsll32.dll
The RedEye plugin depends on several dozen files... see the plugin docs.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to enable detailed error messages to find out what the `500 error` is actually saying.

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995921/imageresizer-remote-reader-plugin-not-working-on-live-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. It was the problem with the server. Actually when this didn't work, i tried to use remotereader plugin but that also didn't work so i tried deploying the code to other server and it worked. So nothing with the code, it was having some problems with the server i was deploying.

Thanks.