# Imageresizer remote reader plugin not working on live site

Tags: imageresizer

I have followed the imageresizer's troubleshooting for when images do not appear as they are listed here:
    Potential causes:

```
You are using the .jpg.ashx syntax, and you did not register the HttpModule properly in both places of your    Web.config file.
You are using the .jpg.ashx syntax, but you're not using a query string. You should drop the '.ashx' unless you actually want to process the file.
You are using ASP.NET MVC, but do not have the MvcRoutingShim plugin installed.
You have Precompilation enabled, and are using an image provider. This is caused by a long-standing bug in the .NET framework.
```

However, everything works perfectly in my local development environment. I have the MvcRoutingShim plugin installed and all the correct web.config references. On the live site, all images referenced by either just a querystring OR the RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl procedure are not found.

All images are resulting in a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, using IIS 8 and app pool is integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: DiskCache(ConfigurationError):  Not working: Your NTFS Security permissions are preventing the application from writing to the disk cache
            Please give user  read and write access to directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot{site}\imagecache" to correct the problem. You can access NTFS security settings by right-clicking the aformentioned folder and choosing Properties, then Security.

Comment: What if I am using a shared hosting?